# Time series forecasting in Shiny in R; Shiny displays unix epoch time

Tags: r, date, user-interface, shiny, time-series

Part of the shiny app I am developing involves time series forecasting. It includes a forecast plot and some tabular information showing the forecasted values over N days. Here is some mock data and a minimal example of the shiny code:-

```
#mock data
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(fabletools)
library(imputeTS)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyquant)
library(ids)


randomid<-random_id(333)
Dates<-structure(c(18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 
                   18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 
                   18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 
                   18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 
                   18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 
                   18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 
                   18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 
                   18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 
                   18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 
                   18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 
                   18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 
                   18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 
                   18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 
                   18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 
                   18263, 18263, 18263, 18263, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 
                   18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 
                   18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 
                   18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 
                   18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 
                   18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18264, 
                   18264, 18264, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 
                   18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 
                   18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 
                   18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 
                   18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 
                   18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 
                   18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18265, 18266, 
                   18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 
                   18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 
                   18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 
                   18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 18266, 
                   18266, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 
                   18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 
                   18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 
                   18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 
                   18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 
                   18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18267, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 
                   18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 
                   18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 
                   18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 
                   18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 
                   18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18268, 18269, 18269, 18269, 
                   18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 
                   18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 
                   18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 
                   18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18269, 18270, 18270, 18270, 
                   18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 
                   18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 
                   18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 
                   18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 
                   18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 
                   18270, 18270, 18270, 18270, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 
                   18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 
                   18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 
                   18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 
                   18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 
                   18271, 18271, 18271, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 
                   18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 
                   18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 
                   18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 
                   18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18272, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 
                   18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 
                   18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 
                   18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 
                   18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 
                   18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 
                   18273, 18273, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 
                   18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 
                   18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 
                   18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 
                   18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 
                   18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 18274, 
                   18274, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 
                   18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 
                   18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 
                   18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 
                   18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 18275, 
                   18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 
                   18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 
                   18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 
                   18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 
                   18276, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 
                   18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 
                   18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 
                   18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 
                   18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18277, 18278, 18278, 18278, 
                   18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 
                   18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 
                   18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 
                   18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 
                   18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 
                   18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 
                   18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 
                   18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 
                   18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18279, 18280, 18280, 18280, 
                   18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 
                   18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 
                   18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 
                   18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18280, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 
                   18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 
                   18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 
                   18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 
                   18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281, 18281), class = "Date")
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(randomid,Dates))
df<-as.data.frame(df)
df$Dates<-as.numeric(df$Dates)
df$Dates<-as.Date(df$Dates, origin="1970-01-01")
```

UI:-

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  tabItem("dashboard",
          
          
          fluidRow(
            
            box(
              title = "Enter Forecast Horison", width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
              h5("Please enter the number of days to forecast"),
              numericInput("forecasthorizon", "Select forecast horizon", 7),
              h5("To zoom in on the plot, specify the date range"),
              dateRangeInput("zoomdaterange","Select date range",
                             start=min(df$Dates),
                             end=max(df$Dates)),
              h5("To edit the y-axis range, input new range below"),
              numericRangeInput("yaxisrange","Select y-axis range",value = c(0,100)),
              h5("Would you like to give your plot a title?"),
              textInput("forecastplottitle","Plot title", "Forecast"),
              
              actionButton(inputId = "click", label = "Forecast")
            )
            
          ),
          fluidRow(
            
            box(
              title = "Forecast plot",
              status = "primary",
              plotOutput("forecastplot", height = 350),
              height = 400
            ),
            box(
              title = "Forecast values",
              
              width = 6,
              tableOutput("forecastvalues"),
              textOutput("winningmodel"),
              height = 380
              
            )
            
            
          )))
```

And server:-

```
#server


server<-function(input,output,session){
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$click,{
    
    
    
    
    
    output$forecastvalues<-renderTable({
      
      #readRDS("Calls.rds")
      
      period<-as.numeric(input$forecasthorizon)
      # more compact sintax
      data_count <- count(df, Dates, name = "Count")
      
      # better specify the date variable to avoid the message
      data_count <- as_tsibble(data_count, index = Dates)
      
      #  # you need to complete missing dates, just in case
      data_count <- tsibble::fill_gaps(data_count)
      
      
      data_count <- na_mean(data_count)
      
      
      fit <- data_count %>%
        model(
          ets    = ETS(Count),
          arima  = ARIMA(Count),
          snaive = SNAIVE(Count)
        ) %>%
        mutate(mixed = (ets + arima + snaive) / 3)
      
      
      
      
      fc <- fit %>% forecast(h = period)
      
      
      res <- fc %>% 
        as_tibble() %>% 
        select(-Count) %>% 
        tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = .model, values_from = .mean) %>% 
        #inner_join(test, by = "Date")%>%
        print(n=Inf)
      
      (res)
    })
    
    # fc_resid<- fit %>% forecast(h = period)
    
    
    output$forecastplot<-renderPlot({
      
      #req(input$zoomdaterange)
      
      eventdate <- as.Date(Sys.Date())
      
      period<-as.numeric(input$forecasthorizon)
      #   more compact sintax
      data_count <- count(df, Dates, name = "Count")
      
      # better specify the date variable to avoid the message
      data_count <- as_tsibble(data_count, index = Dates)
      
      # you need to complete missing dates, just in case
      data_count <- tsibble::fill_gaps(data_count)
      
      
      data_count <- na_mean(data_count)
      
      
      
      fit <- data_count %>%
        model(
          ets    = ETS(Count),
          arima  = ARIMA(Count),
          snaive = SNAIVE(Count)
        ) %>%
        mutate(mixed = (ets + arima + snaive) / 3)
      
      fc <- fit %>% forecast(h = period)
      
      firstzoomdate<-as.Date(input$zoomdaterange[1])
      lastzoomdate<-as.Date(input$zoomdaterange[2])
      
      minyaxis<-as.numeric(input$yaxisrange[1])
      maxyaxis<-as.numeric(input$yaxisrange[2])
      # your plot
      forecastplot <- fc %>%
        autoplot(data_count, level = NULL) + 
        ggtitle(input$forecastplottitle) +
         coord_x_date(xlim = c(firstzoomdate, lastzoomdate),
                                 ylim= c(minyaxis,maxyaxis))
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      plot(forecastplot)
    })
    
    
    
    
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

The graphs are adjustable by changing the date range and ylim values (makes it easier to interpret depending on the data being used). When you click the action button, it runs alright but it returns dates in unix variaion.

[image]

When it should be this:-

[image]

Can anyone point out how I can return the dates in the app that are in `Date` format and not numeric?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `renderTable`, you could just give the `Dates` field the format you want:

```
      res <- fc %>% 
        as_tibble() %>% 
        select(-Count) %>% 
        tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = .model, values_from = .mean) %>% 
        #inner_join(test, by = "Date")%>%
        print(n=Inf)
      # Set format 
      res$Dates <- format(res$Dates,'%Y-%m-%d')
      (res)
```

[image]